# Problem in loading Magick.dll for module Image::Magick?

Tags: imagemagick

Hai
i installed perl 5.10 and after that ImageMagick in my system.
while running the pl files that are present in the demo folder of imageMagick it is saying like this

Can't load 'C:/Perl/site/lib/auto/Image/Magick/Magi... for module Image::Magick: load_file:This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem at C:/Perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 202.

The documentation in perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm states:

> # Many dynamic extension loading problems will appear to come from
>      # this section of code: XYZ failed at line 123 of DynaLoader.pm.
>      # Often these errors are actually occurring in the initialisation
>      # C code of the extension XS file. Perl reports the error as being
>      # in this perl code simply because this was the last perl code
>      # it executed.

How can i fix this problem can anyone suggest me to load the Magick.dll file

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem... nearly pulled my hair out over it.

> Can't load 'C:/Perl/site/lib/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.dll' for module Image::Magick

Then I remembered a note we had in our wiki, and sure enough -- I found the answer on [the ImageMagick site itself](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows):

> If you have any problems, install the
> Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable
> Package (x86) or Visual C++ 2008
> Redistributable Package (x64). 64-bit
> Windows requires both packages (x86 &
> x64).

Installed vcredist_x86.exe and all was well. :::phew!:::